# findOne in findOne result

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been searching all over for this question but it seems like I can't find the exact words to look for that's why I couldn't find the answer. Anyway here's the case:

I have list of Users, Each user has list of friends. (Users can have the same friend). I want to findOne by Id first the User, then a friend on his list of friend.

```
User :
 { firstUser, secondUser }

 firstUser: { name, friendList }
 secondUser: {name, friendList }

 friendList (of firstUser) : {
      { name: Jhon Doe, age: 5 }
      { name: mickey, age: 23 }
 }

 friendList (of secondUser) : {
      { name: Jhon Doe, age: 5 }
      { name: jane, age: 23 }
 }
```

As you can see, I am not able to use $elemMatch and $in because both user can have the same friends.

```
 User.findOne( {id: req.query._id }, function(err, user){
             //what to do here?
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the id of the friend, you would just call `var friend = user.friendList.id(friendId);`

Comment: User.findOne( {id: req.query._id }, function(err, user){
             var friend = user.friendList.id(friendId);

              return friend;  //is this correct?
   });

Comment: no - `return friend;` won't do anything. you have to use the `friend` object within the callback... call another function or do whatever you need, but this is asynchronous code loading from an external resource, and returning from the callback does nothing for you

Comment: unfortunately, this works but i need other way to find the sub document without using .id since i am searching into friendlist by its 'unique_id' i created not by '_id' that mongo created